# Impedir acesso simultâneo TinyRadius

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou utilizando o [TinyRadius](http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/) em uma aplicação Java EE e nessa aplicação não pode ser permitido o acesso simultâneo do mesmo usuário, porém o próprio TinyRadius não implementa tal requisito.

Pensei em algumas maneiras para impedir esse acesso:

- Caso o usuário autentique com sucesso, registre esse acesso em um banco de dados. Quando o usuário deslogar, remover esse registro
- Caso o usuário autentique com sucesso, adicionar esse usuário em uma `List`. Quando o usuário deslogar, remove-lo da `List`

Mas e se o cliente Radius não informar por algum motivo ( desconexão ou outro problema ) que o usuário desconectou? Nas soluções anteriores o usuário iria ficar perdido na `List` ou no Banco de Dados e a próxima autenticação não seria permitida.

Como posso contornar tal situação?

Eis uma implementação de RadiusServer

```
public class TestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) 
throws IOException, Exception {
    RadiusServer server = new RadiusServer() {
        // Authorize localhost/testing123
                    @Override
        public String getSharedSecret(InetSocketAddress client) {
            //if (client.getAddress().getHostAddress().equals("0.0.0.0"))
                return "1234";
            //else
            //  return null;
        }

        // Authenticate mw
        public String getUserPassword(String userName) {
                        System.out.println("Requisitando password... //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            if (userName.equals("gtragoso"))
                return "gtragoso";
            else
                return null;
        }

        // Adds an attribute to the Access-Accept packet
                    @Override
        public RadiusPacket accessRequestReceived(AccessRequest accessRequest, InetSocketAddress client) 
        throws RadiusException {
            System.out.println("Received Access-Request:\n" + accessRequest);
            RadiusPacket packet = super.accessRequestReceived(accessRequest, client);
            if (packet.getPacketType() == RadiusPacket.ACCESS_ACCEPT){
                                    System.out.println("Definindo banda... ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
                                    packet.addAttribute("WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Down", "256000");
                                    packet.addAttribute("WISPr-Bandwidth-Max-Up", "32000");
                packet.addAttribute("Reply-Message", "Welcome " + accessRequest.getUserName() + "!");
                            }
            if (packet == null)
                System.out.println("Ignore packet.");
            else
                System.out.println("Answer:\n" + packet);

            return packet;
        }

                    public RadiusPacket accountingRequestReceived(AccountingRequest accountingRequest, InetSocketAddress client) 
                    throws RadiusException {
                            RadiusPacket answer = new RadiusPacket(RadiusPacket.ACCOUNTING_RESPONSE, accountingRequest.getPacketIdentifier());
                            copyProxyState(accountingRequest, answer);
                            return answer;
                    }
    };

        server.setAuthPort(1645);

        server.setAcctPort(1646);

    server.start(true, true);

    System.out.println("Server started.");

    Thread.sleep(1000*60*30);
    System.out.println("Stop server");
    server.stop();
}
```

Comment: Aí você pode criar um tipo de "sessão" que remove o usuário após '**x**' minutos sem interação com o sistema.

Comment: @renan acredito que isso não funcionaria, pois depois de conectado o usuário não se comunica mais com o Radius (apenas para deslogar).